# Jackson bind List of objects with different name

Tags: json, list, arraylist, jackson

So I have 2 classes:

```
public class Catalog{
 private List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();

 public List<Country> getCountries() {
    return countries;
 }

 public void setCountries(List<Country> countries) {
    this.countries = countries;
 }
}
```

And the second one:

```
public class Country{
 private String name;

 public String getName() {
    return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
 }

}
```

What I want ?
Create the xml but with different names

```
<Catalogue>
    <Countries>
        <Country>
            <name>RO</name>
        </Country>
        <Country>
            <name>RO</name>
        </Country>
    </Countries>
</Catalogue>
```

I write the xml using:

```
    Catalogue catalogue = new Catalogue();

    Country country = new Country();
    country.setName("RO");
    catalogue.getCountries().add(country);
    catalogue.getCountries().add(country);

    String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(catalogue);  // serializing
    System.out.println("The xml is " + xml);
```

How do I do this? 
I tried with @JsonProperty on element, @JsonGetter and @JsonSetter but I'm unable to do this.

When I add those annotations it does something like

```
<Countries>
   <Countries>
      <name>RO</name>
   </Countries>
</Countries>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JacksonXmlProperty` and `JacksonXmlElementWrapper` annotations should work for you:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Catalogue")
class Catalog{

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Country")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Countries")
    private List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();

    //...
}
```