# Java-Jackson Serialize ArrayList<String> to XML with different child names

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I've been using jackson-dataformatter-v2.9.10 to serialize a Java class into an XML string.

This is my class:

```
public class parent()
{
    public ArrayList<String> children;

    public parent() {
       
         children = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
<parent>
    <children>
      <child>John</child>
      <child>Ben</child>
      <child>Mary</child>
    </children>
</parent>
```

Here is what I'm getting:

```
<parent>
    <children>
      <children>John</children>
      <children>Ben</children>
      <children>Mary</children>
    </children>
</parent>
```

Any suggestion on how to change the ArrayList **children element names**?

Comment: You can use `JacksonXmlElementWrapper` annotation. See: [Recursive Nodes In XML Generated By JBPM 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60678696/recursive-nodes-in-xml-generated-by-jbpm-7), [Jackson bind List of objects with different name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59839783/jackson-bind-list-of-objects-with-different-name/59840777#59840777)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use both `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper` and `@JacksonXmlProperty` on the list field.

Here is some sample code:

```java
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "children")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "child")
    private List<String> child = new LinkedList<>();
```

The ElementWrapper is for the outer element
(the one that contains the repeating elements).
The XmlProperty is for the inner element
(the one that repeats).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "children")
List<String> child;
```

https://stackify.com/java-xml-jackson